# Prevent port from being "stolen" by other application

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I have a small daemon-like application which listens on a specific port and it so happens that a different application uses the same port, somehow taking it away from my application.

Before starting that other application everything works fine, once i start it i no longer get a connection, upon closing it however, the daemon continues to work again. I did not know that it was possible to use a port while another application is listening on it and would like to prevent that from happening if possible.

It is also interesting that there is not even an exception when i restart the daemon while the interfering application is already running, it can create, bind and listen on that port, it simply does not work as it should.

Here would be the main loop code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Daemon PID:", os.getpid()
    server = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(('localhost', local_port))
    server.listen(10)
    print "Server listening on:", server.getsockname()

    while True:
        thread.start_new_thread(handle_client, server.accept())
```

(`local_port` and `handle_client` are defined beforehand and should be irrelevant to the issue, system is Debian GNU/Linux 7, Python version is 2.7.3)

---

Additional info as requested:

Running daemon:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     25422/python
```

Running daemon and VLC

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25422/python    
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      25447/vlc       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9000                ::1:46156               ESTABLISHED 25447/vlc       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:46157               ::1:9000                ESTABLISHED -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:46156               ::1:9000                ESTABLISHED -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9000                ::1:46157               ESTABLISHED 25447/vlc
```

---

So the issue seems to be running TCP and TCP6 at the same time. Also noticed that if i first start VLC, then try to run my daemon i do get the expected error, as in this case VLC also grabs the TCP socket.

Comment: I don't have any idea to contribute, but can you check what the other application binds to?  The same port, but what interface or interfaces?

Comment: What's the other application? Is it possible it connects to your deamon's open port (as a client) and blocks you from accepting the connections you would want that way?

Comment: Because what you're describing should in fact be impossible, to my knowledge. You should get an `Address aleady in use` error when the second application tries to bind to the same `host:port` address.

Comment: Also, could you add the output of `netstat -anp | grep $local_port` to the question?

Comment: @LukasGraf: Thanks for the input, added the command outputs to the question which already gets me one step closer to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your daemon is still running on IPv4, while VLC runs on IPv6.  If the application that tries to connect to it were only trying IPv4 it would connect to the daemon; I'd guess that this application is instead first trying IPv6, and using IPv4 only as a fall-back.  You can fix your problem by opening an IPv6 port instead of (or in addition to) an IPv4 port in the daemon, with AF_INET6 and `'ip6-localhost'`.

Comment: Thanks, now running daemon on both protocols using [this module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578504-server-supporting-ipv4-and-ipv6/) without problem :)